# Reducing mouse sensitivity on Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: mouse, kubuntu, libinput

I was forced to upgrade to Kubuntu 17.10 from 17.04. This has the unfortunate side effect that my "Logitech USB Laser Mouse" is super sensitive again. In the past I've used the instructions in questions [such as this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/208230) to reduce it but unfortunately the option `"Device Accel Constant Deceleration"` is not available anymore:

```
➜  ~ xinput list-props 11
Device 'Logitech USB Laser Mouse':
        Device Enabled (145):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (147): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Accel Speed (282):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (283):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (284):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (285):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (286):   1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):       0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (267):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):        0, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (289):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (290):     0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (294): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (295): 2
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (296):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (297):        0
        Device Node (270):      "/dev/input/event5"
        Device Product ID (271):        1133, 49257
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (298):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (299):       1
```

So now I'm looking for alternative ways to reduce the speed and acceleration as using the mouse right now is quite frustrating.

Comment: suggest an update on KDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [libinput](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pointer-acceleration.html#ptraccel-linear) graph suggests you can set the
`libinput Accel Speed` to -1.0 to get a deceleration of 0.5.

```
xinput set-prop 11 'libinput Accel Speed' -1
```

Alternatively, you can try changing the transformation matrix to scale the x and y values.

```
xinput set-prop 11 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' \
  0.5 0 0  0 0.5 0  0 0 1
```

Comment: The first suggestion did the trick, movement feels fine now. I will wait for a bit before accepting but this is good. Thanks.